# Поиск элемента по CLASS

Tags: javascript, dom

Доброго всем!
Подскажите, что значит НОЛЬ в этом коде?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].innerHTML
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("text")` вернет массив всех элементов с классом "text". Соответственно [0] - это получение первого элемента этого массива

Comment: не массив это. пожалуйста.

Comment: @eicto, хм... а что же тогда? В консоли в хроме на этой странице напишите, например `document.getElementsByClassName("vote-buttons")`
В результате вернется массив `[<div class=​"vote-buttons">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"vote-buttons">​…​</div>​]`

Comment: @SergeyTsaplin Это не массив а [Nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/NodeList) , есть большая разница.

[небольшая демка](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/xNDed/)

Comment: @eicto, ОК, был не прав. Спасибо за разъяснения. Никогда не залазил в такие дебри JavaScript'а

Comment: я там ещё workaround сочинил :)  это не дебри javascript это дебри DOM :) javscript тут не причем.